# What information does the rows and columns of heat map gives in convolution neural networks?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have plotted heat map for Convolution neural network. Weight matrix is with 320 rows and 100 columns. 100 columns indicate that I have 100 classes what the row number tells us?

Comment: This questions is difficult to answer in your particular case (because of lack of details about the network architecture and the matrix being talked about) and in general, unless your architecture is relatively simple. The way you put the question, probably 320 is the length of the _high level_ features extracted from your images, which are being linearly weighed by the matrix to produce the logit-probabilities for each class.

Comment: Adding a sample plot might get you more helpful answers.